# Dump a mysql embedded database into a SQL text file

Tags: mysql, dump

I have a mysql embedded database that I need to move into server. I know that for a server I can use mysqldump to backup the data into a SQL text file. But what option do I have for a embedded database?

Thanks,
Carlos.

Comment: Do you mean - how to connect to embedded MySQL server?

Comment: No. I have an embedded server that I connect with Delphi but now I need to move a whole database schema to a mysql server (no embedded). How can I do it?

Comment: This is a database that was created using libmysqld.dll and not by any mysql client program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to dump the embedded schema. I got it from a Amarok tips page

libmysqld.dll enables to use mysql in your program without setting up a server or load a deamon. Also it creates the same files as the server (mysql directory, schema directory and ibdata1 file). So I put those files in a directory and told the mysqld linux deamon to use that directory as datadir:

```
mysqld_safe --user=mysql --datadir=/data/myEmbededDB --skip-grant-tables
```

--skip-grant-tables will allow to connect with any user or password

Because the server point to that directory now I can dump the embedded schema with mysqldump just like any other mysql schema. The same applies if you want to use WorkBench with a schema created with libmysqld.dll

Hope this help other confused libmysqld.dll users

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Make a dump with [mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Then run script with [mysql — The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html)

There are examples, but read about the options. For example for dumping procedures and functions you need to specify '--routines' option, for triggers  '--triggers' option.

Also, you could do it with GUI tools. Try Backup/Restore tools or 'Generate Schema Script' in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Tools allow to select objects in a tree, it is more simply and obvious.

Comment: Hi, How can I configure mysqldump to use my embedded database that is in for example: c:\my_data\my_Embedded_DB ? Because with an embedded db I don't have server name, user, password or port!

Comment: By the way. I use libmysqld.dll and Delphi (Zeos Lib) to access the database

Comment: By the way.. I am using libmysqld.dll and Delphi (Zeos Lib) to access the database.

Comment: Still embedded? OK, I have never connected to embedded with MySQL client. Try to connect with GUI tool, it allows to connect to embedded server.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to embedded server it seems.